# how to export constructor in a declare module

Tags: typescript

I want use inline-style-prefixer like:

```js
var InlineStylePrefixer = require('inline-style-prefixer');

...

var prefixer = new InlineStylePrefixer(userAgent);


...
var _style = InlineStylePrefixer.prefixAll(style);
```

how to export constructor in a declare module?

```js
declare module "inline-style-prefixer"{
    export function InlineStylePrefixer(useagent:string):void; // error
    export function prefixAll(style:Object):Object;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'd do two/three declares:

```
declare class InlineStylePrefixer {
  constructor(useagent: string) {}
}
declare module InlineStylePrefixer {
    export function prefixAll(style: Object): Object;
}
declare module "inline-style-prefixer" {
  export = InlineStylePrefixer;
}
```

When you have a class and a module with the same name, the module is merged with the class.

Comment: This definition pollutes the global scope with declarations for `InlineStylePrefixer`. They should be inside the `declare module "inline-style-prefixer"` block to avoid this.

Comment: I disagree. It's true that this pollutes the global scope but it's intentional. You  have no way of accessing `InlineStylePrefixer` in other definition files without declaring a class globally.

Comment: This is how [bluebird](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/bluebird/bluebird.d.ts#L19) and [chai](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/chai/chai.d.ts#L11) are declared.

Comment: I’m not sure what your point is there; Chai and Bluebird optionally expose globals, if you use them as `<script>` tags in a browser with no loader, so their definition files also expose these global declarations. inline-style-prefixer does not, so far as I can tell. In fact, this definition is not correct for inline-style-prefixer, as it uses ES6 module format so does not export a module value, only a `default` key.

Comment: You are incorrect here. [Chai doesn't export `Chai` to the browser as a global but rather `chai`.](http://chaijs.com/guide/installation/) This style isn't about globals. It's about being able to access this declaration in other declaration files. You can't use `import` in other declaration files because that'd convert your file to an external module. And so you have to export some sort of non-string global module.

Comment: One can use the `import` keyword inside of an external module declaration (i.e. inside a `declare module "foo"` block) within a d.ts file to access other external modules’ type declarations without causing the d.ts file to become an external module. As such, it’s only necessary to expose the types globally in a d.ts file if you are writing a module that shares those types for a global object (as with Chai). Otherwise, it’s mostly just global namespace pollution. (DT definitions aren’t always correct and don’t always follow best practices in this regard though!) I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about that, but consider this case: In nodejs, I want to expose a global bluebird Promise say called `appBootPromise`. I have a file called "bootstrap.ts" which sets `global.appBootPromise`, but I can't let all my other files know about it. What I do is `declare var appBootPromise: Promise<void>` in my `application.d.ts` file. If bluebird hadn't exposed a global `Promise` class then there would be no way for me to achieve that.

Comment: This worked really well for me. Thanks for sharing it! The two additional things I had to figure out were:  

1. I had to add the equivalent of `constructor(useagent:string);` rather than defining the signature on the class declaration itself. I'm guessing that's been a change in TypeScript since this was initially posted.  
2. It took a bit of trial and error before I realized to consume this I needed to do the equivalent of `import * as InlineStylePrefixer from "inline-style-prefixer";`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @KenLyon. #1 was a mistake I'm not sure how I didn't notice. #2 this should work with the import style in the original question `import InlineStylePrefixer = require('inline-style-prefixer');`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I want that `InlineStylePrefixer` will extends another class, for example [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter). I can't import it because I couldn't import it as `import * as InlineStylePrefixer from 'inline-style-prefixer';` I hope you understand my question

Answer (score 5):

I'm using **TypeScript 2.0.10**

Here's my definition that works for [FuzzySearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuzzy-search), which I think is similar to what you want.

The default export is the class, which applies to this kind of import:
`import * as FuzzySearch from 'fuzzy-search';`

The trick is to declare the class and also a variable with the class as the value and make that variable the default export.

**fuzzy-search.d.ts**

```
interface FuzzyOptions {
    caseSensitive?: boolean;
    sort?: boolean;
}

declare class FuzzySearch<T> {
    constructor(haystack: T[], keys: string[], options?: FuzzyOptions);
    search(needle: string): T[];
}

declare var fuzzySearchClass = FuzzySearch;

declare module 'fuzzy-search' {
    export = fuzzySearchClass;
}
```

If you import the class from the module, such as:

`import { Thing } from 'thing-module';`

**thing-module.d.ts**

```
declare module 'thing-module' {
  declare class Thing {
    constructor(someArg: number);
    doSomething(): string;
  }
}
```