# Creating Constructor signature

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am new to typescript, migrating my existing js code to ts code.

Apparently `connect-session-firebase` does not have custom typing so I decided to create one..

this is how I am using it in my code

```
import FirebaseSession from 'connect-session-firebase'

app.use(
            session({
                store: new FirebaseSession({
                    database: context.realtimeDB
                }),
                name: '__session', // Must use this name for firebase hosting
                secret: 'kkkkj9h9', // TODO: Move to ENV
                resave: true,
                saveUninitialized: true
            })
        )
```

Where this is my typing

```
declare module "connect-session-firebase" {
  import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
  import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

  interface firebaseSession {
    database: admin.database.Database | admin.firestore.Firestore, 
    sessions?: string, 
    reapInterva?: string,
    errorIfSessionNotFound?: any
  }
}
```

And I know this is wrong because here `store: new firebaseSession({` I am getting following error

> ```
> this expression is not constructable.
>   Type 'typeof import("connect-session-firebase")' has no construct signatures.
> ```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and How I can fix it?

**Update:**  I updated `firebaseSession` to `FirebaseSession` and tried with `new()` but still no luck

```
declare module "connect-session-firebase" {
  import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
  import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

   interface FirebaseSession {
    new(
    database: admin.database.Database | admin.firestore.Firestore, 
    sessions?: string, 
    reapInterva?: string,
    errorIfSessionNotFound?: any)
  }
}
```

but same error

#### Update : Here is my updated code:

```
import FirebaseSession from 'connect-session-firebase'

app.use(
            session({
                store: new FirebaseSession({
                    database: context.realtimeDB
                }),
                name: '__session', // Must use this name for firebase hosting
                secret: 'kkkkj9h9', // TODO: Move to ENV
                resave: true,
                saveUninitialized: true
            })
        )
```

with types `connect-session-firebase` be

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

declare class FirebaseSession {
  constructor(options: FirebaseSession.Options)
}


declare namespace FirebaseSession {
  export interface Options {
    database: admin.database.Database | admin.firestore.Firestore, 
    sessions?: string, 
    reapInterva?: string,
    errorIfSessionNotFound?: any
  }
}


export = FirebaseSession
```

**Note** while this doesn't throw an error on compile time, it creates equivalent JS code like this

```
const connect_session_firebase_1 = __importDefault(require("connect-session-firebase"));
    app.use(express_session_1.default({
            store: new connect_session_firebase_1.default({
                database: context.realtimeDB
            }),
            name: '__session',
            secret: 'kkkkj9h9',
            resave: true,
            saveUninitialized: true
        }));
```

which throws an error `connect_session_firebase_1.FirebaseSession is not a constructor`

> Cannot read property prototype of undefined.

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384093/how-to-export-constructor-in-a-declare-module

Comment: check my answer first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59026158/cannot-read-property-prototype-of-undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try this like this ?

1) create a type.d.ts with

```
declare module "connect-session-firebase" {
    import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
    export interface OptionsShape {
        database: admin.database.Database | admin.firestore.Firestore, 
        sessions?: string, 
        reapInterva?: string,
        errorIfSessionNotFound?: any
    }

    export interface FirebaseSession {
       new(n: OptionsShape): void
    }

    export class FirebaseSession {
       constructor(n: OptionsShape);
    }

    export default FirebaseSession;
}
```

2) import your module and use it (it should be typed and not complain about type any

```
import FirebaseSession from 'connect-session-firebase'

var firebase = new FirebaseSession({
 //params
});
```

EDIT : As I say in my comment, you can fix the compile like this, but the thing is now it's up to you to make the correct types for the libraries. I do not know the library, so I don't know what is the return value of `new FirebaseSession({})`, or what `FirebaseSession` has as properties and method...

You have to read the package and adapt your `types.d.ts` to it, so that it works flawlessly. You can probably get help from the package creator, and make a `@types/connect-session-firebase` when done. But if it's just for the compiler to work, you can keep patching (but is not recommended)

```
declare module "connect-session-firebase" {
    import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
    import { Store, MemoryStore } from 'express-session';
    export interface OptionsShape {
        database?: admin.database.Database | admin.firestore.Firestore, 
        sessions?: string, 
        reapInterva?: string,
        errorIfSessionNotFound?: any
    }

    export interface FirebaseSession {
       new(n: OptionsShape)
    }

    export class FirebaseSession extends MemoryStore {
       constructor(n: OptionsShape);
    }

    export default FirebaseSession;
}
```

Comment: `Argument of type '{ store: FirebaseSession; name: string; secret: string; resave: true; saveUninitialized: true; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SessionOptions'.
  Types of property 'store' are incompatible.
    Type 'FirebaseSession' is not assignable to type 'Store | MemoryStore | undefined'.
      Type 'FirebaseSession' is missing the following properties from type 'MemoryStore': get, set, destroy, touch` this is the error I am getting on compile time

Comment: well, you have to play with the type now to make it works

Comment: @anny123 if you are adding type to the library, you have to make it works with the correct return types, parameter etc... that FirebaseSession return.

to fix the above error you can import 

`import { Store, MemoryStore } from 'express-session';` and change this line to this 

`export class FirebaseSession extends MemoryStore` 

but now this is a "tricks", if you are typing the library, you have to know what are the exact type returned by the library. so you should read the code of `connect-session-firebase` and type it as needed.

Comment: @anny123 any news ?

Answer (score 0):

To mark an interface as constructable, you give it the `new(...)` "method" (more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)):

```
interface firebaseSession {
    new(/*...param declarations here if appropriate...*/): firebaseSession;
    // ...
}
```

I'd also strongly recommend making any constructible types initially capped (`FirebaseSession` rather than `firebaseSession`) if possible.

Comment: I am not sure if I did it correctly or not but still the same error. Updated the question

Comment: @anny123 - Note that your update doesn't give a return value for `new`. You should be getting an error about that. What happens if you do what's shown in the answer?

Comment: @anny123 - The updated question is also inconsistent. Are you using `firebaseSession` or `FirebaseSession`?

Comment: Sorry, My bad. Added couple of screenshots for your reference